# Search Related Lists for a value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I have 3 Custom Lists. List A = Clients List B = Policies List C = Commissions. List B and C have a Lookup Field called "Client" that references List A.

I need a way to search all three lists to create a view that displays all clients with policies that have not received any commissions.

Is this possible or is it possible to create this with a Workflow?

Comment: Is server side coding allowed then webpart can be created.

Answer (score 0):

Using content search web part is ideal, however, I am no aware of any way to connect the 3 lists in the query text.
My suggestions to you is to use Web Part connections and you can play with the views to show a connection with no Commissions
You can connect data in web parts using web part connections.

Here is a good [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-data-in-Web-Parts-c9a84132-44be-4abb-94d1-d69cfdc052db) on the subject!

Answer (score 0):

A no code option would be to use SharePoint Designer for creating an agregated view of all 3 lists. SPD offers the option to create a "linked source" where you can have multiple lists acting like one data source. Once linked you can add filters and define your overview using a data view webpart. Please have a look [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-Data-View-f9898d20-a5ab-4973-9d16-9f4e4c088ae1) for an example.